# Generate and save XML file

Tags: php, xml

This is what I am trying to do:

When I click a button, a XML structure is created and a save-as dialog box 
appears to ask the user where to save it.

In general, everything is fine.

The problem is: *the saved file contains XML structure AND js, html code*.

This is how my code looks like:

```
/*a lot of code before */

$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domtree->formatOutput = true;
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("xml");
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
//create and append other elements

//save it to a file using a dialog box
$file_name = "myFile.xml";
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $file_name);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $domtree->saveXML();

/* a lot of code after */
```

I do realize the problem could be about headers or stuff echoed before.
But I don't know how to fix it.

I found solutions for similar situations but it looks like the source file contains only the code that generates and saves XML file.

In my case, I need more code around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fixed the problem:

I added

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

before echo and

```
exit;
```

after echo.

Now the code looks like this:

```
/*a lot of code before */

$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domtree->formatOutput = true;
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("xml");
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
//create and append other elements

//save it to a file using a dialog box
$file_name = "myFile.xml";
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $file_name);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $domtree->saveXML();
exit;

/* a lot of code after */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to me (Did not test it, but it looks valid and will execute correctly), and I also assume that whatever is in *$xmlRoot* is also valid.

How exactly are you implementing the XML file download link ? is it a link to a php file that is containing the code above ?

In order for the XML to be downloaded as a file, you need to have your code run as a "XML file generator" - that means that the "generator" creates the file and returns it in a downloadable format to the browser (triggering the download prompt on the browser end).

**The classic method works like this,**

The generator returns a header in the following format:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myFile.xml');
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

And then the XML output:

```
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

It is important that nothing (not even a single whitespace) will be printed before the headers.

Then, A download link can look like this:

```
<a href="http://api.my-domain.com/download-as-xml/document/123">Download as XML</a>
```

Once the end-user clicks on it, he will be prompted on if he would like to save the file to his computer (some browsers are doing this automatically without asking)

**If you are looking to do the same with ajax** it's a completely different story.

Hope it helps a bit!

Comment: I wrote the code having the classic method in mind. The problem was that the saved file contained also js, html code, not just the XML structure desired. Adding ob_clean, flush and exit fixed the problem. But it's still unclear for me what happened. Thank you for your contribution!