# How to add headers to XML file, created in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a code which is taking data from database and creates an XML file. I need to add such headers to the xml file.
Needed headers:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header('Content-Desposition: attachment; filename="products.xml"');
```

Original php code:

```
<?php

      include('dbconnect.php');

      function loadXML(){

           global $dbh;
           $result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM stock_infos;");
           $name = strftime('products.xml');
           $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<nuts/>');
           while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                $nut = $xml->addChild('nut');
                $nut->addChild('code',$row['code_product']);
                $nut->addChild('name_product',$row['name_product']);
                $nut->addChild('in_stock',$row['in_stock']);
                $nut->addChild('date_stock',$row['date_stock']);


           }
           $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
           $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
           $dom->formatOutput = true;
           $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
           $dom->save(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$name);



      }
      loadXML();
?>
```

How the the code should look in the end, so the XML files would be generated with needed headers?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to send this XML file to the users browser

Comment: Could [Generate and save XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436375/generate-and-save-xml-file) be relevant?

Comment: XML doesn't have such headers, it is only relevant in a HTTP context.